# How can I display an integer variable as thier intended ASCII letters in `cout` when parsing a binary file?

Tags: c++, cout

When I use `hexdump -C` on the command line to examine this MIDI file, we can see that some bytes of this binary file are ASCII letters that are meant to be human readable text.

```
00000000  4d 54 68 64 00 00 00 06  00 01 00 08 00 78 4d 54  |MThd.........xMT|
000024f0  2f 00 4d 54 72 6b 00 00  00 19 00 ff 21 01 00 00  |/.MTrk......!...|
00002500  ff 03 0c 62 79 20 42 65  65 74 68 6f 76 65 6e 00  |...by Beethoven.|
00002510  ff 2f 00 4d 54 72 6b 00  00 00 18 00 ff 21 01 00  |./.MTrk......!..|
```

For debugging purposes, when I have a variable that holds an integer that I know represents a string of ASCII characters, I would like to simply display the ASCII characters in `cout`.

I this case, the first four bytes of the file are `0x4d546864`, which represent the letters `MThd`.

```
uint32_t n32Bits = 0;
ifs.read((char*)&n32Bits, sizeof(uint32_t));
n32Bits = BigEndianToLittleEndian(n32Bits); // reverse byte order
```

This is the integer:

```
std::cout << "n32Bits: " << n32Bits <<std::endl; // 1297377380
```

I can easily display it as hex:

```
std::cout << "n32Bits: " << std::hex << n32Bits <<std::endl; // 4d546864
```

Now, I want this line to output the letters `MThd` just like `hexdump` does.:

```
std::cout << "n32Bits: " << std::ascii << n32Bits <<std::endl; // compile error.
```

Isn't there some simple built-in way to dump ASCII letters from integers that represent ASCII letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no formatting spec like `std::ascii` but there is a `string` constructor you can use:

```
std::string int2str((char*)&n32Bits, 4);
std::cout << "n32Bits: " << int2str << std::endl;
```

This constructor takes a `char` buffer and length.

Comment: This seems to work, except that it outputs `dhTM` instead of `Mthd`, unless I place the first line of your code before the endian conversion. Or in otherwords, it seems to print a reversed ASCII value when given an integer after the byte order swap. But the byte order swap is required to get the correct integer value.

Comment: @Nick if you look at the hex dump you posted, the string values are not big endian. The first byte in the file is 'M' and this will also be the first byte you want printed. I don't know what the "correct integer value" is for you. If you are comparing against a magic number someone decided to write out as big endian, that is a representation problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look into that more. The MIDI spec says multi-byte values are stored big endian but perhaps certain text (like chunk IDs) isn't, or perhaps the test file I'm using is non-compliant. But this solves the issue of being able to quickly dump ASCII for debugging, so I'm marking it as the answer.

Comment: @Nick usually, when specs say "multibyte values" they refer to integer types such as short, int, etc. Strings have no meaning of "endiness" so any value that is meant to be interpreted as string will always be stored in English order. This can get a bit confusing with "file magic" (not just for MIDI) where sometimes the "magic" is treated as integer, but can also be viewed as a readable string.

Comment: @Nick also, when integers are written in hex representation for humans to read, they are always written "Big endian" i.e. the highest byte will be on the left, first after 0x. This will be the case even if in the file or in memory it is stored as little endian. This can also be confusing, but it is done so because we humans are used to reading numbers left to right. Sometimes in documents "big endian" refers to "paper" or "human readable" representation which adds to the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in function to print raw bytes as an ASCII string the way a hex dump does.  You will have to do that yourself manually, eg:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>

char buffer[sizeof(n32Bits)];
std::memcpy(buffer, &n32Bits, sizeof(n32Bits));

std::transform(std::begin(buffer), std::end(buffer), std::begin(buffer),
    [](unsigned char ch){ return std::isprint(ch) ? static_cast<char>(ch) : '.'; }
);

std::cout << "n32Bits: ";
std::cout.write(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
std::cout << std::endl;
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/44czAZ)

Answer (score -2):

```
int a = 0x4d546864;
// swap_bytes(a);
int b[] =   {a, 0};

cout << (char*)b <<endl;
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.